# Getting multiple matches via regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to retrieve a strings from a global string via Matcher & Pattern using REGEX.

```
String str = "<strong>ABC</strong>123<strong>DEF</strong>"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<strong>(.*)</strong>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
```

My problem is that the matcher gives me just one match that is inside the global tag strong:

```
ABC</strong>123<strong>DEF
```

My objective is to get 2 matches:

```
ABC
DEF
```

Thank you very match for you help.

Answer (score 3):

You need a non greedy regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<strong>.*?</strong>");
```

Use `?` to specify non greedy. This means it will match the first match it finds instead of the outer most match...

If you only want `ABC` and `DEF` then you can do something like this using lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
String str = "<strong>ABC</strong>123<strong>DEF</strong>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=<strong>).*?(?=</strong>))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

If you do a google search you should be able to find information on lookaheads and lookbehinds...

Comment: If you only want ABC and DEF then you can use capturing groups:

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<strong>(.*?)</strong>"); 

and then matcher.group(1)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use `JSOUP` to parse your `HTML` code instead of regex as

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<strong>ABC</strong>123<strong>DEF</strong>");

    // select your tag
    Elements elements = doc.select("strong");

    // get the iterator to traverse all elements
    Iterator<Element> it =  elements.iterator();

    // loop through all elements and fetch their text
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next().text());
    }
```

Output :

```
ABC
DEF
```

or get Output as single string

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<strong>ABC</strong>123<strong>DEF</strong>");
    Elements elements = doc.select("strong");
    System.out.println(elements.text());
```

Output:

```
ABC DEF
```

[Download Jsoup](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsoup160jar.htm) and add it as a dependency

Comment: In case , `Jsoup` has lot of other function like , to download your html content using `Jsoup.connect(URL)` and other parsing and selection functions